# Error de un decorador dentro de una clase en python3

Tags: python-3.x, decoradores

Tengo un problema en python3, creo un decorador dentro de una clase y no funciona

```
 def decorador(self, function):
     def funcion_interna:
         # acciones adicionales que decoran
         function()

 @decorador
 def funcion(self):
     print("saludo")
```

Error:

```
TypeError: database_managment() missing 1 required positional argument: 'function
```

Pero si, le quito el **'self'** al decorador, funciona sin problema:

```
 def decorador(function):
     def funcion_interna:
         # acciones adicionales que decoran
         function()

 @decorador
 def funcion(self):
     print("saludo")
```

Entonces tengo la duda si es correcto lo que estoy haciendo, si hay una manera diferente de hacerlo, etc.

También vi por ahí que hay clases de decorador sobre métodos especiales **'__call__'** y **'__get__'** algo así... que no entiendo mucho.

Entonces mi duda es:

> ¿Que debo utilizar y cual es la mejor opción?

Y también tengo la duda de:

> ¿Porque al quitarle el **'self**' al decorador funciona correctamente?

**¡¡Y de antemano gracias por sus respuestas!!**

---

**Actualisacion(Resuelto):**

Intente de esta manera y funciona con el **'self'**, pero no se si esta es la manera correcta?

```
def database_managment(self, *args):
    def connect_database(*args):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('database/Bank-Data')
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        function(*args)
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()

    return connect_database
```

Comment: El código que has pegado en la actualización ¿forma parte de una clase o está fuera de todas? Por otro lado ¿cómo aplicas el decorador `database_management`? Entiendo que estás con el mismo problema que al principio, pues ese decorador espera dos parámetros, pero cuando lo uses le pasarás sólo uno (la función que lleve detrás). Y por último ¿la función que vas a decorar es miembro de una clase o es una función aparte?

Comment: Es miembro de una clase.

Comment: Y La aplico para manejar la base de datos

Comment: Nose como explicarlo ya que recién empece a desarrollar mi programa... El decorador lo utilizo para manipular la base de datos, para insertar datos y crear, tablas hasta este momento.... Nose si esta info es útil, Quieres que haga otra actualisacion y ponga el código completo?

Comment: Pues sí, por favor, pon el código completo o si es demasiado largo pon un enlace a algún sitio donde pueda verlo (por ejemplo un pastebin), pues no acabo de entenderte.

Comment: Ok ya lo puse..

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90467/discussion-between-abulafia-and-julio-cesar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque en el título de la pregunta mencionas "dentro de una clase", el código que pones como parte de la pregunta no muestra ninguna clase. Por otro lado ese código es en general incorrecto porque el decorador que has escrito no retorna la función interna (y hay un error de sintaxis en la definición de esa función porque faltan los paréntesis).

Supongamos que lo que querías hacer era algo como esto:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def decorador(self, function):
      def funcion_interna():
          print("Decorada empieza")
          function()
          print("Decorada termina")
      return funcion_interna

  @decorador
  def funcion(self):
       print("saludo", self.name)
```

La intención es por tanto definir un decorador como método de una clase, y usar ese decorador para decorar otros métodos de la misma clase.

Lo anterior no funciona, como has descubierto. Ya que el método `decorador()` espera dos parámetros (`self`, y `function`), pero luego lo usas poniendo `@decorador`, asumirá que la función que aparece detrás será el primer argumento a pasarle al decorador (tomará el lugar de `self`) y le faltará entonces un segundo parámetro `function`.

Si quitamos sin más el `self` de la declaración del decorador y lo dejamos así:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def decorador(function):
      def funcion_interna():
          print("Decorada empieza")
          function()
          print("Decorada termina")
      return funcion_interna

  @decorador
  def funcion(self):
       print("saludo", self.name)
```

Tampoco estaría bien. Aunque esta vez el código anterior no produce errores al ser ejecutado, ha definido una clase que no se comportará correctamente. Si probamos a instanciar esta clase y llamar a su método `funcion` lo vemos:

```
>>> a = A("Pepe")
>>> a.funcion()
TypeError
----> 1 a.funcion()
TypeError: funcion_interna() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

¿Qué pasó? Que al hacer `a.funcion()` en realidad se invoca el método pasándole como primer parámetro (en `self`) la referencia al objeto. Es decir, se está ejecutando `A.funcion(a)`. Esto a su vez, ya que la función ha sido decorada, se traduce en que lo que realmente se ejecutará será `funcion_interna(a)`, es decir, a la función interna se le está pasando como parámetro el objeto sobre el que actúa. Pero la declaración de la función interna no espera tal parámetro, y de ahí el error.

Hay que añadir a `funcion_interna()` un primer parámetro que será el objeto sobre el que actúa. Esta función llama internamente a `funcion()`, y *deberá* pasarle también ese objeto pues `funcion()` lo espera (lo recibirá en `self`). Es decir el código final que sí funcionará es:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def decorador(function):
      def funcion_interna(obj):
          print("Decorada empieza")
          function(obj)
          print("Decorada termina")
      return funcion_interna

  @decorador
  def funcion(self):
       print("saludo", self.name)
```

---

```
>>> a = A("Pepe")
>>> a.funcion()
Decorada empieza
saludo Pepe
Decorada termina
```

### Nota final

¿Por qué quieres el decorador dentro de la clase? Funcionará exactamente igual si está fuera:

```
def decorador(function):
    def funcion_interna(obj):
          print("Decorada empieza")
          function(obj)
          print("Decorada termina")
    return funcion_interna

class A:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  @decorador
  def funcion(self):
       print("saludo", self.name)
```

Esta forma es algo más limpia, pues no tienes dentro de una clase un método que no recibe `self` como primer parámetro (lo que puede resultar chocante a quien lo lea, e incluso generar errores en *linters* y editores). Además de ese modo el decorador puedes usarlo en otras clases.

## Ampliación (respondiendo a la ampliación de la pregunta)

El usuario publica su código, en el que intenta usar de nuevo el decorador como un método de una clase, con esta sintaxis:

```
def database_managment(self, *args):
    def connect_database(*args):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('database/Bank-Data')
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        function(*args)
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()

    return connect_database
```

y dice que le "funciona".

Lo cierto es que ese código no puede funcionar por dos razones:

1. El decorador tiene más parámetros de los que debería. Un decorador sólo puede recibir un parámetro, y aquí tiene `self` más `*args`. Funciona aparentemente porque `*args` podría estar vacío. Pero entonces `self` no representará al objeto de la clase, sino a la función que va a ser decorada.
2. Dentro del decorador hay una llamada a `function(*args)`, la cual dará un error porque `function` no está declarada, ni es un parámetro ni nada.

No obstante estos errores no se descubrirán hasta que no intente ejecutarse una función decorada con ese decorador. Ya que en este caso el código es parte de un programa que usa Tk, y que las funciones están asociadas a botones, el error no se descubre hasta que se pulse uno de esos botones. Por eso el programa "arranca sin problemas" y puede pensarse que está correcto, pero fallará al pulsar un botón.

La sintaxis correcta para el decorador sería:

```
def database_managment(function):
    def connect_database(obj, *args):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('database/Bank-Data')
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        function(obj, *args)
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()

    return connect_database
```

Como vemos en esta sintaxis no hay referencias a `self`, por lo que este decorador puede escribirse dentro o fuera de la clase, de forma indistinta. Yo aconsejo fuera, porque tener dentro de una clase un método que no use `self` sería confuso.